# Differentiate $\cosh(x^2)$

Tags: calculus

I came across some exponential and logarithm practice problems at liavas.net and made my way through all of them and came to the final question 3. Find the derivative of $y=\cosh(x^2)$
And so I proceeded with the chain rule $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx}$$ And now we let $y=\cosh(u)$ where $u=x^2$ therefore $\frac{dy}{du}=\sinh(u)$ and $\frac{du}{dx}=2x$
And so $\frac{dy}{dx}=2x\sinh(x^2)$ no?
The solution shown has $\frac{dy}{dx}=2x\sinh(x)$ and I was wondering where I've gone wrong.

Comment: you're right, probably just a typo

Comment: You are correct; the solutions are wrong.

Comment: Indeed, there should be a square on the $x$ inside that hyperbolic function, +1) for showing your steps!

Comment: Link http://liavas.net/courses/calc2/files/Exp_and_log.pdf